# LuaLaTeX: Are there functions missing?

Tags: luatex

Is it possible that LuaTeX is incomplete with respect to things that are referenced for example in the LuaTeX Reference?

My engine is: LuaTeX, Version 0.95.0 (TeX Live 2016) (format=lualatex 2017.1.20)

What does not seem to work are at least the following:

```
\directlua{tex.sprint(number.dimenfactors["mm"])}
\directlua{tex.sprint(number.tocentimeters(100000))}
\directlua{tex.sprint(1,'pt')}
```

The first two commands I found at http://wiki.contextgarden.net/Dimensions, and the last in the manual at http://www.luatex.org/svn/trunk/manual/luatex.pdf

### EDIT: MWE

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
number.dimenfactors: \directlua{tex.sprint(number.dimenfactors["mm"])}
number.tocentimeters: \directlua{tex.sprint(number.tocentimeters(100000))}
print two objects: \directlua{tex.sprint(1,'pt')}
\end{document}
```

The result is:
[image: Output from MWE above.]

The first two lines do not create the desired output, but cause these two (unfortunately not very instructive) errors in the log file:

```
[\directlua]:1: attempt to index global 'number' (a nil value)
stack traceback:
    [\directlua]:1: in main chunk.
l.3 ...ectlua{tex.sprint(number.dimenfactors["mm"])}

The lua interpreter ran into a problem, so the
remainder of this lua chunk will be ignored.

[\directlua]:1: attempt to index global 'number' (a nil value)
stack traceback:
    [\directlua]:1: in main chunk.
l.4 ...lua{tex.sprint(number.tocentimeters(100000))}

The lua interpreter ran into a problem, so the
remainder of this lua chunk will be ignored.
```

The third command just outputs the string in the second argument, but not the number in the first.

Comment: Wecome to TeX SX! Try updating: present version is `1.0`.

Comment: @Bernard - There's currently an admittedly odd discrepancy in versions of LuaTeX across the two main TeX distributions: MikTeX features version 1.0, but TeXLive still features version 0.95.

Comment: @Mico: I had no idea of that. It's been quite a few months MiKTeX has version 1.0!

Comment: What do mean by "seem not to work"? I get no error with texlive and miktex and the output is identical when I add the commands to a minimal document.

Comment: Can you post a "minimal working example" that illustrates the problem? (Basically a complete (La)TeX file that you ran in lualatex and got unexpected results. There's more about [minimal working examples here](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that).)

Comment: Thanks for your comments! Since I am using MacTeX, I guess I cannot update yet to version 1.0. Is that correct?

Comment: Did you update your mactex? It will probably not give you version 1.0 but it will bring you to the same versions Ulrike is using

Comment: I am using TeX Live Utility 1.26 (up to date) and updated all packages. Is that what you mean? I think Ulrike is using MiKTeX instead of MacTeX.

Comment: For what it's worth, I can confirm I get the same results as you (the same errors etc.) on my (rather ancient) `LuaTeX, Version beta-0.80.0 (TeX Live 2015) (rev 5238)`.

Comment: BTW, your last error is easily explainable: you have not read the documentation carefully; the argument `n` is not something that is printed by `tex.sprint`: the documentation says: "The optional parameter can be used to print the strings using the catcode regime defined by `\catcodetable n`. […] Otherwise, if n is not a valid catcode table, then it is ignored, and the currently active catcode regime is used instead."